# Unlimited integer increment running time

Tags: performance, time, time-complexity

I was asked in a job interview to build a 'simple' unlimited integer.

I was given endless space and time, so for 'simplicity' I just used a linked list of digits (0-9).

An 'increment' operation increments the first digit and cascades an increment to the next one if it's 0 (was 9 initially).

So far so good.

Then I was asked what is the run time for such an increment operation, given a random initial state.

I got kinda stuck on it, started talking about sums of logarithms on bases 10^n and such, when the interviewer got frustrated and told me it's constant time.

I can't figure it out by myself, but it seems to me that it can't be constant.

Please, can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: It is only O(1) when the answer is 42.  Count yourself lucky that you didn't get the job.

Comment: Single increment might take linear time, but he probably meant it is amortized constant time - average runtime of `k` increments would take time `O(k)`.

Comment: It was a big company, one you can only dream of going to work in for your 1st job...